# Let $Z_t=\int{W_s }ds $. Show that $Z_t=\int (t-s) dW_s$

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let $Z_t=\int_{0}^{t} W_s ds$. Use integration by parts to show that $Z_t=\int_{0}^{t} (t-s) dW_s$.
I have tried and i can't get the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Note that
\begin{align*}
d(sW_s) = sdW_s + W_s ds.
\end{align*}
Then you can integrate on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

For $Z_t  = \int_{0}^{t} W_s \,ds$, 
\begin{align}Z_t &= \bigl[sW_s\bigr]^{t}_{0} - \int_{0}^{t} s\,dW_s\\
&=tW_t - s(W_t) \\
&= (t-s)W_t\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}(t-s) dW_s
\end{align}
where I used the property that $\int_{a}^{b} c\,dW_t = c(W_b - W_a), \, c$ is an arbitrary constant, and $W_0 = 0$

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: How come you extract the s and then include the t-s if they are not constant?